# openGL glUnmapBuffer() returning unknown error code 1280

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer

I am writing some proof-of-concept code. I want to prove that I can write data to a buffer object after the buffer has been created. However, I am getting a a GLenum error code of 1280 when I try to unmap the buffer after writing to it. I am completely stymied.

I can initialize the buffer the with color data and successfully render it. The problem is that I cannot modify the data in the buffer afterwards. The code is below. It shows how I write the new data to the buffer and then how I try to read it back. The error codes are shown in comments after the glGetError() calls. The variable "cbo" is the color buffer:

```
//NEW COLOR DATA
GLubyte colorData2[9] = {255,255,0, 0,128,255, 255,0,255};

//WRITE THE DATA TO THE COLOR BUFFER OBJECT (variable cbo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
int err1 = glGetError();  //Error code 0

//Oddly, glMapBuffer always returns and invalid pointer.
//GLvoid * pColor = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT); 

//However, glMapBufferRange return a pointer that looks good 
GLvoid * pColor = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 9, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
int err2 = glGetError(); //Error code 0

// Copy colors from host to device
memcpy(pColor, colorData2, 9);

//Unmap to force host to device copy
glUnmapBuffer(cbo);
int err3 = glGetError(); //Error code 1280

//Unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
int err4 = glGetError(); //Error code 0

//******TEST THE WRITE******
GLubyte readbackData[9];
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
int err5 = glGetError(); //Error code 0
GLvoid * pColorX = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 9, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
int err6 = glGetError(); //Error code 1282

//Mem copy halts because of a memory exception. 
memcpy(readbackData, pColorX, 9);

glUnmapBuffer(cbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Here is the code where I created the buffer object:

```
//Create color buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &cbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);

//Create space for three RGB 8-bit color objects
colorBufferSize = 3 * numColorChannels * sizeof(GLubyte);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferSize, colorData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//Unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1280, or 0x0500, is `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

`glUnmapBuffer` takes the enum where the buffer object is bound, not the buffer object to unmap. `glUnmapBuffer` expects the buffer object to be unmapped to be bound to that binding target. So `glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)` will unmap whatever is currently bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why glMapBuffer() fails, but glMapBufferRange() suceeds? Thanks, Aaron